Use GOTO Statement once without multiple iterations
I'm trying to return a question if user inserts an invalid input using C++. I'm using goto statement but the problem is it keeps looping the question over and over again not allowing the user to input anything in the command prompt.
Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int human_years, dog_per_human_age, dog_years;

starthere:

    cout << "How many years ago did you buy your dog?" << endl;
    cin >> human_years;
    if (cin.fail() || std::isnan(human_years))
    {
      cout << "Non numerical value inserted! Please try again.\n";

      goto starthere;
    }
    else
    {
        dog_per_human_age = 5;
        dog_years = human_years * dog_per_human_age;

        cout << "Your Dog is " << dog_years << " years old.";

        return 0;
    }
}

Valid input snippet
Invalid Input Snippet
I'm trying to return a question if user inserts an invalid input using C++. I'm using goto statement but the problem is it keeps looping the question over and over again not allowing the user to input anything in the command prompt.

Don't.... Use a loop instead, such as while. You also need to fix the formatting.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Time to learn how to use your debugger :)

Does this answer your question? How to reset std::cin when using it?

If a stream ends up in a failed state, you need to reset that state. And clear the current input as it will not have been discarded. Generally it's almost always better to read the whole line as a string, and then try to convert the string to the type you want, with validation. And if you need to read multiple values, create a function to do the input and validation.

As for your current code, besides what have been said about goto, don't include <bits/stdc++.h>. Also, using namespace std; is also a bad habit. And std::isnan is for floating point numbers, not integers. An integer can never be a "nan".

A side note: goto statement considered harmful.

goto is a red herring

For future questions, don't post images of text. Copy-paste all text as text into your questions.

Here is another reason why you shouldn't use goto, with the reason being the amount of help you will get in future problems, whether deserved or not.  If you ask questions about code not working, and the code has goto's, you will reduce by a significant amount the people that will help you with the code.  Many programmers will not try to waste time untangling code that uses goto.

Even I strongly recommend not to use goto, but if you really want to use the same you can just add cin.clear and cin.ingnore(1000,'\n') before calling the goto statement. What it does is it clears the buffer up to the character that you want. (The 1000 is put there to skip over a specific number of chars before the specified delimiter, in this case, the '\n' newline character.)
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int human_years, dog_per_human_age, dog_years;

    starthere:

    cout << "How many years ago did you buy your dog?" << endl;
    cin >> human_years;
    if (cin.fail() || std::isnan(human_years))
    {
      cout << "Non numerical value inserted! Please try again.\n";
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
      goto starthere;
   }
    else {

    dog_per_human_age = 5;
    dog_years = human_years * dog_per_human_age;

    cout << "Your Dog is " << dog_years << " years old.";

    return 0;

    }

}


You are making spaghetti code. You would be probably interested in making some research before rejecting the well known good programming practices
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Using cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); will most likely be sufficient, but may not be sufficient if the input is longer than 1000 characters. As stated in the documentation of the function, you can read in an unlimited number of characters if you specify std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() instead. In my opinion, doing this is a good habit, unless you have a specific reason not to do it.

You took over std::isnan(human_years) from OP's code, which I believe was not meaningful, for the reasons stated in the comment to the question.

The problem which cause the loop is the failed state which is stored in std::cin (since, as you wrote the code, it tried to store a lettter into a integer field).
In order to reset the cin's flag, you have to call cin#clear() and cin#ignore(); the latter one will ignore one-char per called-time (you have to call it n-times as the amount of inserted letters); otherwise you will could call its overloaded function, passing the amount of chars to ignore.
As "Some programmer dude" said, you should avoid read into an integer type directly, instead read it as a string via getline() - please read about difference between them by yourself - and then parse string
if (cin.fail() || std::isnan(human_years))
{
  cout << "Non numerical value inserted! Please try again.\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
  goto starthere;
}

Edit:
As lost of people already said, it is striclty avoided goto using; you oughta prefer using while loop with a flag

Besides still using goto as a loop, if the user input multiple invalid inputs there will be a lot of error messages, one for each invalid input character.

Yep dude, therefore I've just edited my answer to add yours tip about avoiding it ;)

This ignores only one single character. Consider change it to ignore the whole line at once.

I've already said it...2nd paragraph...

I strongly advice learn programming without goto. The presence of goto is a sign of wrongly structured program. Before learning to use goto, learn to not use it.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int human_years, dog_per_human_age = 5, dog_years;

    cout << "How many years ago did you buy your dog?" << endl;
    cin >> human_years;
    while (cin.fail() || std::isnan(human_years));
    {
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
      cout << "Non numerical value inserted! Please try again.\n";
      cin >> human_years;
    }


    dog_years = human_years * dog_per_human_age;

    cout << "Your Dog is " << dog_years << " years old.";

    return 0;

}


You neglected to mention the actual fix you introduced. Using while instead of goto was not it.

Oh, yeah, that's correct, the cin.clear(). I think the author will be able to spot it. The question itself mentioned goto, so I wanted to emphasize it.

There's another important part missing: If there is invalid input, it will not be removed from the input buffer. Your loop will read the same invalid input over and over again, in an infinite loop.

@Someprogrammerdude taken in consideration

In C++, goto isn't the "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" (1968) by Edsger Dijkstra kind of goto.  C++ goto is a structured goto, not the harmful unstructured goto that Edsger was upset about.  That being said, there's are better language constructs to use in the OP's code, such as the while that you used here.  (std::isnan will never trip for an int.)

@Eljay The presence of goto is itself a sign of wrongly structured program. And it is used mostly in conjunction with an if to simulate an if/else or a loop, and it is exactly what is author doing there. So, what I said is Before learning to use goto, learn to not use it.. It means, learn to structure correctly your code. About std::isnan, not a concern at all in this code, even it doesn't make sense for ints.
